# Como detener un bucle for sin usar un break?

Tags: python, python-3.x

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una lista de números de los cuales debo encontrar uno usando búsqueda lineal, pero lo que sucede es que cuando encuentro dos números repetidos en la lista la iteración debe detenerse SIN USAR BREAK, este es el código:

```
p = [2, 10, 23, 23, 41, 45, 57, 90]
num = 23

t = bool(False)
print('\nNumber:',num) 
    

for z in range(0,len(p)):
    if p[z]==num: 
        for i in range(z+1):
             print('\nIteration:',i,',L[',i,']','=',p[i])
             i+=1
        
        print('\nNumber found in the position:',z)
        t = True
    

if t == True: 
    print('\nAmount of Iterations:',i) 
else: 
    print('\nNumber no found, try again')
```

Comment: Por qué sin break?

Comment: No se como será en python, pero si estas usando un contador, podrías frenar  el ingreso usando ese mismo contador. Si el numero se ha repetido 2 o mas veces, no entraras el loop. Como referencia ´ for ($i = 0; $i<2; $i++)´ // Con i menor a 0, si es que i es menor a 2, i se seguira sumando...

Comment: Usa un bucle while en lugar de un for

Comment: Aca hicieron la misma pregunta, solo que es SO en ingles -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773965/breaking-out-of-python-loop-without-using-break

Comment: Si se vale usar funciones, puedes salir del ciclo poniendo un `return datos_calculados` cuando se cumple la condición.

Comment: @PabloLozano Parece que el desafio impuesto es con el for de todos modos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay dos requisitos un tanto chocantes en la pregunta:

- No usar `break`. ¿Por qué? Es una instrucción perfectamente válida y de hecho la única que tiene sentido usar en este contexto (otras soluciones son increíblemente complicadas como veremos)
- Usar `for` ¿por qué? No es la estructura de control apropiada cuando quieres iterar solo hasta que se cumpla una cierta condición. En Python el `for` de hecho no es una estructura de control convencional, es un iterador, y permanecerá iterando hasta que el iterable se agote. La estructura de control natural para bucles interrumpibles es `while`.

## Problema de ejemplo

Vamos a generar números de 0 a 1000, pero dentro del bucle queremos parar cuando el número alcance el valor 5.

## Usando `while`

En este caso no generamos números con un generador, sino que tenemos una variabl que vamos incrementando:

```
i = 0
while i<5:
   print(i)
   i = i+1
```

Si quieres, también puedes hacer uso de una variable booleana que te diga cuándo parar de iterar:

```
i = 0
seguir = True
while seguir:
   print(i)
   i = i + 1
   if i==5:
      seguir = False
```

## Usando `for` y `break`

```
for i in range(1000):
  print(i)
  if i == 5:
     break
```

Aunque el iterador `range(1000)` no se agota hasta haber generado los 1000 elementos, sin embargo rompemos el bucle cuando sólo ha generado 5.

## ¡Mira mamá! ¡sin `break`!

Si no usas `break` sólo hay una forma de hacer que `for` deje de iterar, y es que el iterable sobre el cual estaba iterando se agote.

Un iterable como `range(1000)` no se agotará hasta haber generado 1000 números. Pero podemos crear una función generadora que retorne antes de haber generado 1000, y que podamos controlar con una variable booleana externa. Por ejemplo así:

```
seguir = True
def range_con_stop(n):
  for i in range(n):
    if seguir==False:
      return
    yield i
```

Esta funcíón es similar a `range()`. En cada iteración devuelve un número más (en el `yield`), pero si `seguir` se hace `False`, el generador terminará. Esto podemos aprovecharlo para implementar el bucle `for` buscado así:

```
for i in range_con_stop(1000):
  print(i)
  if i==5:
    seguir = False
```

Otro enfoque, más retorcido si cabe, es usar una expresión generadora y cerrarla dentro del bucle cuando queramos salir. Así:

```
generador = (x for x in range(1000))
for i in generador:
   print(i)
   if i==5:
      generador.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

**Usando for dentro de una función**

Como ya sugirieron, puedes poner el `for` dentro de una función y ejecutar un `return` en lugar de un `break`.

En el fondo es la misma cosa, escrita de otra manera.

La función `buscar` retorna el índice de la primera ocurrencia. Si no hay repetición, devuelve -1.

```
def buscar(numero, lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[i:i+2] == [numero, numero]:
            return i  # Encontrado!
    return -1  # No encontrado.

p = [2, 10, 23, 23, 41, 45, 57, 90]
posicion = buscar(23, p)
print(posicion)
```

**Usando excepciones**

En lugar de `break`, levantamos una excepción con `raise` que nos saca del `for`.

La variable `posicion` tiene el indice de la primera ocurrencia, o -1 si no se encontro.

```
p = [2, 10, 23, 23, 41, 45, 57, 90]
numero = 23
posicion = -1

try:    
    for i in range(len(p)):
        if p[i:i+2] == [numero, numero]:
            posicion = i
            raise StopIteration
except:
    pass

print(posicion)
```

Comment: Un par de comentarios. Puestos a elevar excepciones, tiene más sentido que sea `StopIteration` :-) Y por otro lado, el try/except creo que debería englobar el for en vez de estar dentro. De lo contrario no evitas que siga iterando. Puedes comprobar esto si metes otro par de 23 más adelante en la lista. `posicion` apuntará al último par de 23 detectados, en vez del primer par.

Comment: @abulafia. Toda la razón. Edite la respuesta con tus comentarios.